# How to add/remove class on hover using tailwind?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, tailwind-css, hidden

Is there any way to remove class once the object is hovered using tailwind classes?

```html
<span className='group inline-block relative'>
  Hello
  <span className='hidden absolute -top-16 left-16 group-hover:inline-block'>&#45;</span>
</span>
```

Here I want to remove the `hidden` class once the object is hovered which means it would be hidden at first(when the page is loaded) but once it is hovered the object stays put.

Before:

[image]

Result needed:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Your code is working. It something with positioning `-top-16 left-16` - correct values of these classes (like `top-4 left-4` etc)

Comment: That's not the issue, issue is simply I want to remove the "hidden" class after I hover the object, it could be achieved by jQuery but I want to know if there is any way to do that using tailwind css.

Comment: You already have done this with `group-hover:inline-block`. If you wish to remove class completely - no, Tailwind works only with CSS

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know if it's possible to remove it completely. But thank you, I'll achieve it by using jQuery then.

Comment: Again - you've already achieved desired [result](https://play.tailwindcss.com/4mVm6B1K3v) - I see no point to use jQuery or any Javascript. But if you task requires to remove this class completely, then yes - you have to use Javascript

Answer (score 1):

To add a class on hover using tailwind, you can use the :hover pseudo-class. For example, if you wanted to add the class "hover:bg-red" to an element when the user hovers over it, you would use the following CSS:

.selector:hover { class:bg-red; }

To remove a class on hover using tailwind, you can use the :not(:hover) pseudo-class. For example, if you wanted to remove the class "hover:bg-red" from an element when the user hovers over it, you would use the following CSS:

.selector:not(:hover) { class:bg-red; }

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

Use `group` class to group the elements and then add `group-hover:flex` to display that subsequent  child element. Else remain that child to be `hidden`

```html
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <div class="container mx-auto p-10">
    <div class="flex-col space-y-5">
      <!-- without hover -->
      <div class="bg-black text-white uppercase text-xl p-2 mx-auto w-min">hello</div>
      
      <!-- with hover -->
      <div class="group bg-black text-white uppercase text-xl p-2 mx-auto w-min">hello
        <div class="bg-white w-16 h-2 group-hover:flex hidden"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```